# Pex pipe to garden. What are advantages of 3/4 in vs 1/2

Tags: plumbing, pex, hose

I have read many posts similar to this, but have not drawn a conclusion.

My hose bibs are 1/2.
I am running pex out to the garden.  Probably 150-200 foot run, connecting 2-3 garden hose bibs.

I know that 3/4 will allow more water to flow, but if the 1/2 house bib can only supply 1/2 amount of water is it worth the extra $125 to upgrade to 3/4 pex?

Comment: I think not.  You usually want 3/4 to 1/2, not not 1/2 to 3/4.  The pressure will be reduced.  Matters for sprinklers not so much for drip lines.

Comment: @crip659 Thank you.  That will save me some $